# Is it possible to generate superscript in HTML from a string variable using RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, superscript

Is there a way to create superscript in `rmarkdown` in string?

If I have a string - `acceleration"`, I want to include the unit next to like `"acceleration (m/sec^2)"` so that when it's rendered to HTML table column names, it should show up as

acceleration (m/sec<sup>2</sup>)

All column names should have their units next to the name, that's why I'm trying to do this.

I tried:

```
names(vars) <- c("", ...,"acceleration m/sec \\textsuperscript{2}")
names(vars) <- c("", ...,"acceleration $m/sec^2$)
```

and other variations.. but didn't work. I keep getting error on these when I `knitr`. Is it possible, so that when I render it to html that it produces the superscript correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markdown notation is `^.^` and `~.~` to write super and subscripts.

```
testdata <- mtcars[1:2]
names(testdata) <- c("", "acceleration (m/sec^2^)")
knitr::kable(testdata)
```

[image]